# ASP.NET jquery function call

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Suppose an **ASP.NET .NET 3.5 Site.**

There is an `asp:TextBox` defined with this **jquery** **javascript** attached to it:

```
$("#myTextBox").change(function() {});
```

which means that if the user changes the text value, this function will be called.
And of course it works.

The problem is that I've made a button in which's `EventHandler` it automatically fills this `TextBox` with the default value. A round trip / page reload occurs and a new value is correctly set. With the difference, that the jquery function `change()` **is not called**;

And i need to call that function because it sets a variable to decide whether the text has been changed.

**EDITED:**

The variable is set to check if the user provided some input. If that's the case, it offers him the possibility to save it.

The problem isn't that the variable is not set, when someone clicks on the Button (which makes a value auto-fill), the problem is that the Button causes the page to be reloaded and the var value is lost. And i need to keep the value until the user tries to leave the page.

**REFLECTION**

Perhaps I could set cookies across the page reloads ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should be setting this other variable, the one that indicates whether the value has changed or not, from the code-behind when the value changes.  In other words, it looks like you need to do this in two places.

Alternatively, you could change the button to set the value via javascript, and set it's OnClientClick handler instead of it's OnClick handler.  Make sure the end of the OnClientClick returns false, to avoid the postback.   In that case, you'd be able to avoid the postback altogether, and your problem would be solved.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="someId" OnClientClick="$('#myTextBox').val('someValue');return false;"/>
```

Comment: OK but the Button click receives and parses the Data from MS reporting.. and then these data are used as the value for the TextBox. How could I do that in OnClientClick ? Sorry, I'm not used to write anything in js..

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to adjust the ID if it's inside anything:

```
$("#<%=myTextBox.ClientID %>").change(function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, you know server-side if the value has changed. Then just make sure that you output

```
$('#myTextBox').change();
```

when this is the case. You could put this code inside a placeholder and in the button event handler toggle a bool determining whether the placeholder is rendered or not.

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock is a fantastic feature (if you're stuck in ASP.NET-land) - look it up. =)

Comment: Ah, right. I jumped the ASP.NET MVC bandwagon years ago, so I had forgotten about that one :-)

Comment: I *wish* I could jump that particular bandwagon.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$('[id$=myTextBox]').change();
```